# Hollow conductor for transmission line

Tags: conductors, power

A hollow conductor can transfer almost the same current when compared to a solid conductor with less material requirement due to the skin effect. But still, we use solid stranded conductors for a transmission line. Why is it so?

Comment: Overhead transmission lines typically are _not_ "solid conductors." They typically have a conductive outer layer (aluminum strands) wrapped around an inner, structural core (steel or carbon fiber). The structural core would be needed even if there were no skin effect because aluminum does not have sufficient tensile strength to span the distance between towers.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for your response. There is a conductor called AAAC which is made of only aluminum too. And loss in tensile strength can be compensated with reduced span if the material saving in aluminum is significant.

Comment: I did not know that, but [here it is](https://www.prioritywire.com/specs/AAAC%20-%20All%20Aluminum%20Alloy%206201%20Conductor.pdf). So, I _guess_ the answer must come down to the cost. Seems like the total cost a given length of AAAC with a given current carrying capacity and a given tensile strength, must be less than if the same length of wire with similar ratings was "bulked up" with a non-conducting central core. Consider that "total cost" is not just the cost of manufacturing and material, but also includes things like, increased cost of transporting and installing the bulkier wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high power lines often use multiple cables with spacers. The thickness of the layer of conductive strands in each cable approximates the skin depth. So, they achieve the efficient use of material you seek by different means.

Comment: I agree, also, manufacturing might be a challange